# In apache pulsar producer batching is working or not

Tags: java, apache-pulsar

In Pulsar Producer, I am unable to track if batching is working or not. If it is working, I would like to know how to track it

I tried enabling the batching feature in pulsar producer and used the below methods while creating the producer object:

1. enableBatching(boolean enableBatching)
2. batchingMaxBytes(int batchingMaxBytes)
3. batchingMaxMessages(int batchMessagesMaxMessagesPerBatch)
4. batchingMaxPublishDelay(long batchDelay, TimeUnit timeUnit)

but I am not able to track if batching is working in pulsar producer or not and below is the line I am getting while enabling pulsar client debug logs
** add message to batch, num messages in batch so far 0**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.